# There is something else than a "DllMain" in a module for its initialization?

Tags: dynamic-linking, pe32, compiler-optimization

All right, Actually I am manually mapping a module into a process, actually my mapper calls `DllEntryPoint` from standard struct `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` thus `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS::OptionalHeader::AddressOfEntryPoint` etc...

The problem:
consider following code:

```
void Log(const char*, ...);


class Test
{
    private:
        struct List_t
        {
            const uint32_t x;
            const uint32_t y; 
        } List;

    public:
        Test(List_t z) : List(z) { Log("Called event 0! \n"); }
        ~Test() {}
};



void Entry()
{
    Test Instance
    (
        {
            0x200,
            0x400
        }
    );

    Log("Called! \n");  
}


BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{

    if(fdwReason == 1)
        Entry();

    return TRUE;
}
```

so if the module entry point gets called through `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS::OptionalHeader::AddressOfEntryPoint` from mapper, the constructor `Test()` never gets executed, while that `Entry()` function gets executed successfully, now if the module it's loaded with standard `LoadLibraryA();` so `Test()` constructor gets called successfully...

Where i would find some information about this?

I have heard something about `CRT` initializers, but i can't find anything deeply...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of programs you'd also have to watch out for [TLS callbacks](https://wiremask.eu/articles/tls-callbacks-assembly-x86-64/). These run prior to the entry point, but I have only ever seen those on .exe files, never on DLLs. Still, Peter Ferrie stated that TLS callbacks exist for DLL files. I'd trust his expertise on this, even though I've never seen one of those myself, when reverse engineering a DLL.

Anyway, `DllMain` in your case has that `fdwReason` parameter. That one is kind of important here and you should not have used a literal `1` there but the [proper symbolic name: `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain).

`DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`, `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`, `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` are the currently defined values. A `switch` statement would therefore be much more sensible here.

Depending on the reason for which you're being called back in `DllMain` you can act.

Now while I don't know if that class is meant to be a singleton, it's clear that all that happens inside `Entry()` is the creation *and* destruction of an instance of that class on the stack. Once the scope of that function is left, the instance will be destroyed. You should be able to verify this by adding something like a `Log()` invocation to the dtor.

As for the CRT initializers, yes these exist. Kindly read [this other answer by me](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2089/245) before reading on.

...

Okay, assuming you read my answer, the difference between `DllMain` as expected by the CRT when you build with the default CRT is that it already includes that CRT initialization code you likely mean. Whereas if you told the linker to use an alternative `/entry` you would still use the same prototype for the DLL entry function, but you'd have to deal with initialization. Literally all the information you may need is in the above linked answer to that related question *and* inside the files mentioned in said answer.

Comment: Yes, it happens the same using a singleton class, tls callbacks were behind this all time... i am gonna fix this on my mapper... edit: looks like happens through tls callbacks when there stuff statically initialized...