# Start vs WinMain()

Tags: ida, malware, dll, exe, entry-point

I am trying to analyze a malicious DLL and when I loaded it in IDA, I can see two functions - `DLLEntryPoint` and `DLLMain`. I then proceeded to change the format by switching the characteristics bit that identified the file as a DLL to an EXE. When I load the file again in IDA, I can see two functions - `Start` and `WinMain`

From what I understand, `Start` is the entry point for an exe and it does some initialization before it calls `WinMain` or `Main`. Are `DLLEntryPoint` and `DLLMain` similar functions for Dlls?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Maybe have a look [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2089/245)?!

Answer (score 2):

First, please [read this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2089/245).

Essentially the difference is (in both cases) that one - the entry point - refers to the address where the initial code will be located and the other - "main function" - will be the one provided by the (C) runtime, potentially hiding gory details from you.

> From what I understand, `Start` is the entry point for an exe and it
>   does some initialization before it calls `WinMain` or `Main`. Are
>   `DLLEntryPoint` and `DLLMain` similar functions for Dlls?

This is almost correct. `Start` *is* the symbolic name of the entry point in this case, true. However, whether it performs some kind of initialization depends entirely on the library. I wager IDA has recognized some runtime library (such as the Visual C++ runtime) by way of a FLIRT signature and used that information to point out `DllMain` to you.

Conceptually `DLLEntryPoint` and `DLLMain` mirror what you found for `.exe` files, yes.